# How to show indexes of NAs?

Tags: r, indexing

I have the piece to display NAs, but I can't figure it out.

```
try(na.fail(x))
> Error in na.fail.default(x) : missing values in object
# display NAs
myvector[is.na(x)]
# returns
NA NA NA NA
```

The only thing I get from this the length of the NA vector, which is actually not too helpful when the NAs where caused by a bug in my code that I am trying to track. How can I get the index of NA element(s) ?

I also tried:

```
subset(x,is.na(x))
```

which has the same effect.

EDIT:

```
y <- complete.cases(x)
x[!y]
# just returns another
NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: But why numeric indices are more helpful than logical ones?

Comment: @Marek, I was loading some dataset to R, ran a function on the df. The result was that some NAs where introduced due to coercion. The function does work... so obviously something was wrong with the imported file. Since the file was pretty large and I did not know where to look for I looked for a proxy for linenumbers :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You want the which function:

```
which(is.na(arr))
```

Comment: Jesus. This is it. Thanks Jivlain. If which was somehow part of the See also section of is.na, it would have saved an hour or two. Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

***is.na()*** will return a boolean index of the *same shape* as the original data frame.

In other words, any cells in that m x n index with the value *TRUE* correspond to NA values in the original data frame.

You can them use this to change the NAs, if you wish:

```
DF[is.na(DF)] = 999
```

To get the total number of data rows with at least one NA:

```
cc = complete.cases(DF)
num_missing = nrow(DF) - sum(ok)
```

Comment: thx, for the answer. unfortunately is does not cover my problem yet. The NAs were introduced by coercion in my case (because of some problem with a custon function). Thus I'd like to know which lines are those NAs lines. There are 4 NAs out of 100K+ lines and would like to know which ones.

Answer (score 2):

which(Dataset$variable=="") will return the corresponding row numbers in a particular column

Answer (score 0):

#### R Code using loop and condition :

```
# Testing for missing values

is.na(x) # returns TRUE if x is missing

 y <- c(1,NA,3,NA)

 is.na(y) 

 # returns a vector (F F F T)

 # Print the index of NA values

 for(i in 1:length(y)) {
  if(is.na(y[i])) {
   cat(i, ' ')
  }
 }
```

#### Output is :

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvBSc.png)

#### Also :

```
which(is.na(y))
```